# How to have two delegates to a class which I cannot change

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, delegates

There is a class `MyView` which may have a delegate `MyViewDelegate`. I cannot change `MyView` and `MyViewDelegate. When something interesting happens with a`MyView` object, it notifies delegate about it.

The delegate protocol is something like this:

```
-(void)view:(MyView *)view event1_Happened;
-(void)view:(MyView *)view event2_Happened;
...
-(void)view:(MyView *)view event10_Happened;
```

I have a class `MyLib` which holds a weak reference to `MyView` object. And it needs to listen to these interesting events from `MyView`. In other words, `MyLib` would be happy to be a delegate of `MyView`.

I have a `MyViewController` which holds strong references to both `MyLib` and `MyView`:

```
@property(nonatomic) MyView *view;
@property(nonatomic) MyLib *lib;

self.lib = [[MyLib alloc] initWithView:self.view];
self.view.delegate = self.lib;
```

This works just fine.

But! `MyViewController` also wants to listen to `MyView` events. It means it wants to be a delegate of `MyView` as well as `MyLib` does.

I know two possible ways how to handle it.

1) Make `MyView` holding an array of delegates. It is not the way to go, because `MyView` is "sealed".

2) Forward delegate events. It means I have to write ten methods in `MyViewController` like this:

```
-(void)view:(MyView *)view eventN_Happened {
    // do something with this notification
    ...
    // forward it to MyLib
    [self.lib view:view eventN_happened];
}
```

N goes from 1 to 10. Not good too (too much code).

Is there any possibility to solve this in elegant way?

In one of the scenarios

```
MyView = MKMapView
MyViewDelegate = MKMapViewDelegate
```

but I am not sure it is a relevant info.

Comment: The second approach is the only one available.  You can tweak it by writing a "delegate multiplexer", which would be a separate object which can be assigned as the delegate.  It, in turn, would forward to any number of registered observers.

Comment: Am not 100% on your setup -- do you have access to change the protocol of MyView?  Usually if you need multiple objects to listen for events from a single sender an observer pattern is used.

Comment: Why don't you use NSNotificationCentre to broadcast and listen to these event. Either post from origin of event or from delegate